EC2 Instances Failing to Communicate with AWS Elastic Beanstalk Due to VPC/EC2 Configuration Issues
I have been working on the full-stack course, and I am on the AWS part, but I am having some issues with getting it to work, as the videos for it are now different from the layout for creating the instance. I have tried to use my intuition in setting up following the video, but I can not get the environment to work. I am wondering if anyone can help with this.
August 15, 2024 16:36:06 (UTC+1)
ERROR
The EC2 instances failed to communicate with AWS Elastic Beanstalk, either because of configuration problems with the VPC or a failed EC2 instance. Check your VPC configuration and try launching the environment again.
August 15, 2024 16:36:06 (UTC+1)
ERROR
Stack named 'awseb-e-uxy3xm2t2p-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBInstanceLaunchWaitCondition]. 
My template has this: 
Service role
arn:aws:iam::242201283214:role/ElasticBeanstalkEC2Role
EC2 key pair - amigoscode 
EC2 instance profile - ElasticBeanstalkEC2Role

Network VPC: vpc-04c0c33bb8d0003ad
Public IP address: true
Instance subnets: subnet-09c7948e5eed2ab71,subnet-05096597f42453378,subnet-0ee8a021de0a34c5d
Database Database availability: false
Has coupled database: true
Database deletion policy: Delete
Database engine: postgres
Database engine version: 16.3
Database instance class: db.t3.micro
Database password: ******
Database storage: 20
Database subnets: subnet-09c7948e5eed2ab71,subnet-05096597f42453378,subnet-0ee8a021de0a34c5d
Database username: amigoscode


Tried changing the form, rerunning it, filling it in as best I could.
I expected the EC2 instances to successfully communicate with AWS Elastic Beanstalk, allowing the environment to deploy and manage the application.

you need to create VPC first , create pulic and private subnet , create route table and then launch your elastic beanstalk in that vpc in public subnet , while creating the elastic beanstalk you need to create security group allowing the request to com from internet to you 80  and 443 port, and also allow ssh port 22 so that you can shh into instacne incase of some issue and outbound to all. lastly if you dont want this all setup just lauch your elasticbeanstalk in default vpc and make sure to allow 80,443  and 22 in inbound rule and outboubn rull to all .
